# Why to use jsp:forward

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

As per my personal opinion, JSP are good for display output. And separated java class (say servlet/action etc) are good for writing rest programming logic. However some java code may require on JSP page to display output correctly.

Writing some code over JSP for only processing purpose then redirecting to another JSP, would be useful only if JSP has some extra features that other java classes/servlet/action dont have.

Please tell me some real time applications where we should use `jsp:forward`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal opinion, JSP has no extra features that other java classes/servlet/action don't have.

A JSP is just a servlet in disguise.